# Создание и удаление input'ов по value

Tags: javascript

Есть инпут в которой будет добавляться текст. При заполнении maxlength нужно создать новый и сделать фокус на него. При стирании символов - удалить инпут и перести также фокус. 
Пытался через createElement, но не осилил. Слаб в js
Сейчас вот такая вот демка есть https://jsfiddle.net/1j5s5g7c/

```
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

one.onkeydown = function() {
  if(one.value.length == 10) {
  two.style.display = 'block';
  two.focus();
 }
}

two.onkeydown = function() {
  if(two.value.length == 0) {
  two.style.display = 'none';
  one.focus();
 }
}
```

Но тут просто скрываем и открывает input, а нужно в добавлять/удалять элемент в DOM. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято вот отсюдо: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id

Создаете такую вот конструкцию:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

После этого вы можете удалять элементы вот так:

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove()
```

Для добавления элементов используете:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("идентификатор рабочего инпута").parentElement;
var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
// тут добавляете нужные данные к инпуту
parent.appendChild(newInput);
```

Это один из многих способов :)

Comment: Вот еще ответ, прям как мой : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853779/adding-input-elements-dynamically-to-form

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую) сообщу о результате)